# Как вывести значение из массива введя его ключ в input?

Tags: php

Всем привет! Я только начинаю изучать PHP помогите решить задачу)

На станице есть поле input в него я должен написать ключ из раннее созданного  массива, а при отправке мне должно возвратить значение этого ключа.

Вот массив:

```
$data = array(
    "Привет" => "Хай!",
    "Как дела?" => "Отлично!",
)
```

Вот форма:

```
require 'data.php'; // Подключаем массив
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["text"]);
$respond = "Error!";
if (($_POST["text"]) == "Сюда получаем ключ из input") {
    echo "Сюда приходит значение введенного ключа из массива";
} else {
    echo "$respond";
}

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="key">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Может у вас есть свои варианты, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Вывести значение по ключу:

```
if(!empty($data[$name])) {
    echo $data[$name];
} else {
    echo $respond;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST["text"]) && array_key_exists($_POST["text"], $data)) {
    echo $data[$_POST["text"]];
} else {
    echo "$respond";
}
```

Документация: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-exists.php